# Why can't I implement an interface which has a bounded generic type in this code in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface Successorable<E> extends Comparable<E> 
    E suc();
}
```

and

```
interface IInterval <E extends Successorable<E>> {
    E min();
    E max();
}
```

I'm trying to implement IInterval by doing:

```
public class Interval<E> implements IInterval<E> {
 ....
```

However eclipse complains that the type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<E extends Successorable<E>>` of the type `IInterval<E>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to restate your conditions. The plain old `E` in `Interval<E>` doesn't necessarily fulfill `E extends Successorable<E>` so you need to be more specific about your parameter.

```
public class Interval<E extends Successorable<E>> implements IInterval<E> {
    @Override
    public E min() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public E max() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by more specific? I tried to replace E with 'E extends Successorable<E>' but it doesn't work. I'm a newbie at this...

Comment: I've tested the answer that I gave and it compiles handily. Have you tried it just as I posted?

Comment: I'll add, don't always trust the eclipse compiler, double check that javac is producing the same answer from the CL

Comment: I commented before you showed the code example, yes it works, thanks!